# Place a comment on a specific post in PHP, the postid is given in the URL

Tags: php

I'm doing a project for school, it is some similar as Instagram. So you can post a photo on your timeline and then other users can place a comment on this photo.

This comment option is succesfully done: You can place a comment and the comment comes into the database.

**Comment classe: PHP code**

```
<?php

include_once "Db.class.php";

class Comment
{
    private $m_sComment;



    public function __set($p_sProperty, $p_vValue)
    {
        switch($p_sProperty)
        {
            case "Comment":
                $this->m_sComment = $p_vValue;
                break;
        }      
    }

    public function __get($p_sProperty)
    {
        $vResult = null;
        switch($p_sProperty)
        {
        case "Comment": 
            $vResult = $this->m_sComment;
            break;
        }
        return $vResult;
    }

        public function Save() {
            $conn = Db::getInstance();
            //$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $statement = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO comment(comment, postID) VALUES(:comment, :postID)');
            $statement->bindValue(':comment', $this->Comment);
            $statement->bindValue(':userID', $this->Comment);
            $statement->execute();
        }

        public function GetRecentActivities($p_iPostID) {
            $conn = Db::getInstance();
            $allComments = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE postID = <post_id> ORDER BY id DESC;");
            return $allComments;
        }

    }

?>
```

But now the question is: In the URL of the post, i send a specific POSTID. 
http://localhost/oefening/post.php?p=9&u=8

p => PostID

u => UserID

How can i send tis postID to my database ?

Answer (score 0):

its not exact answers you have to enhance

```
<?php
    $url = "http://www.vnoel.com?cmd=list";  // The simple url
  $name = "option";                        // The parameter name
    $value = "new";                          // The parameter value
  $newUrl = $url . "?$name=$value";        // appending the values

  // prints:http://www.vnoel.com?cmd=list?option=new
    print($newUrl);
  ?>
```

in destination page you have to receive using ** $_GET['option']**